# extract and Plot K fold results for various models

Tags: r, cross-validation, r-caret

I have to build a couple of models and validate their stability through 10 fold CV

I have the following code for a logistic regression and nnet
 for example

```
mod_fitlog <- train(form,  data=x, method="glm", family="binomial",
                 trControl = ctrl, tuneLength = 5,verbose=T,metric='auc')

mod_fitnnet <- train(form,  data=x, method="nnet",preProcess = "range",
                trace = FALSE, maxit = 100)
```

Now i want to extract the results of 10 cv runs , i.e. 10 aucs for each modelling and plot them - basically to judge which model is more stable and which isnt with higher variance .

Comment: It's easier to help if you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data so we can run the code.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you look at [pipelearner](https://github.com/drsimonj/pipelearner) which was written for exactly this kind of task.